# How to get the IP address from the domain name in R

Tags: r, dns, network-programming, lookup

I have a csv containing domain names, for which I want to find out IP Addresses for an application.

Is there any way to do this in R. Is there any R libraries to do this?

Comment: E.g. `devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/iptools"); library(iptools); ip_to_hostname("173.194.123.10")`? I'm on Windows and it seems the package is not available there.

Comment: On Windows you might wanna use `nslookup`: `(res <- shell("nslookup google.com", intern = TRUE))`.

Comment: @lukeA  Works also on Linux.

Comment: @lukeA: I've already tried using this package in Linux. But for some reason,  my R session is aborting whenever i try to use either `ip_to_hostname()` or `hostname_ro_ip()` function

Comment: @ManojG  Does it hang with `hostname_to_ip()` examples?

Comment: @Pascal: Yes. I'm getting an error saying `R encountered a fatal error, the session was terminated` and asking to start new session whenever I use both the functions.

Comment: @ManojG  Strange. Works fine on my Linux.

Comment: @Pascal: Sorry. It works in R console. It fails in RStudio. Just figured out. Thank you. I can do what i wanted in R console. But wondering why did it not work in RStudio!

Comment: That's a good question! I'll take a look today. Are you able to share some or all of the CSV file? Also, if you could move discussion to the issue I just filed for this it'd prbly save this thread from getting the "extended discussions" SO warning : https://github.com/hrbrmstr/iptools/issues/20

Comment: @hrbrmstr: I can share CSV file. How and where do i share the file?

Comment: not sure if github lets you drag a CSV over yet. if so you can do that. otherwise Dropbox/Gdrive/etc. I've got access to all. You can shoot it to bob at rudis dot net too.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: unable to drag csv in github. So sent email.